# soffice converted .ods file ,Failed to read .ods file using jOpenDocument API

Tags: java, xls, ods, jopendocument

I have converted **.xls** file to **.ods** by using below command in terminal

```
COMMAND : soffice --headless --convert-to ods abcd.xls
```

After conversion I am not able to read **fileName.ods** using **SpreadSheet API** of **jOpenDocument1.3.jar**. When ever I try to read .ods file it will throw **NullPointer Exception** .

I am working in Ubuntu platform, if I convert **.xls** file to **.ods** using **LibreOffice** then it is working fine but if I convert it using **soffice** terminal then it is throwing exception!.

Is there any way to convert file(s) using command line, so that Java code able to read it properly.

I am using below code to read converted **fileName.ods** file .

```
File file = new File(path);
String sheetName = "SheetName"; // spread Sheet Name
Sheet sheet = SpreadSheet.createFromFile(file).getSheet(sheetName);
```

"**createFromFile**" is giving NullPointer Exception

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jopendocument.dom.ODPackage.getODDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.jopendocument.dom.ODPackage.getSpreadSheet(Unknown Source)
    at org.jopendocument.dom.spreadsheet.SpreadSheet.createFromFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.thales.dbtool.controller.DBManageController.getUiParamsFromExcel(DBManageController.java:1316)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandl
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check if `file.exists()`. I would bet on that. PS : That's wonderful to have a nice [java doc](https://www.jopendocument.org/docs/org/jopendocument/dom/spreadsheet/SpreadSheet.html#createFromFile(java.io.File)) ! That's helping...

Comment: @AxelH file.exists() it is giving true, I able to get file object as well

Comment: I found this page showing the same kind of error : https://github.com/mmulqueen/odswriter/issues/4

Comment: Include the jopendocument source jar in your project to find the actual problem. If I trust [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jopendocument/jOpenDocument/1.3/org/jopendocument/dom/ODPackage.java#ODPackage.getODDocument%28%29), either `this.getContentType()` returns null in `final ContentType ct = this.getContentType().getType();` or `ct` is assigned `null`in that statement.

Comment: Oh, if `file.exists()` returns `true`, what do `file.isDirectory()` and `file.canRead()` return?

Comment: Meh, just [some poor code](https://github.com/denixx/jOpenDocument-1.3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jopendocument/dom/ODPackage.java#L607-L618). He's calling `getContentType()` method while it simply returns `this.type`. (Yet `this.type` is used more frequently...) Iff you look to the usage of `this.type` (especially initializations) in that package... then * shivers *. Eh, look also at [`createFromFile`](https://github.com/denixx/jOpenDocument-1.3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jopendocument/dom/ODPackage.java#L260)

Comment: @Axel file.isDirectory() is giving false and file.canRead() is true

Comment: A comment in the constructor said "_fill in the missing types from the manifest, if any_". Since this is not working with `soffice`, I would guess it didn't fill the "manifest" corretly, so the type is never defined.(thanks to @KarelG for the github). It's only a guess for now.

Comment: soffice --headless --convert-to ods abcd.xls  : this command convert the file which is larger then the actual file .if actual abcd.xls file is 1.9 mb then converted abcd.ods file size is 14.5 mb ,is conversion is not correct ,is it missing any header ?